# Linked list with file IO

Tags: c, file-io, linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string>

struct link_list {
    char mail[50];
    int counter;
    struct link_list *next; 
               };

    typedef struct link_list node;

    void main()
    {
        FILE *fp ; 
        char string1[80]; 
        node *head=NULL; 
        int count_length=0; 
        char *fname = "email.txt";
        fp = fopen ( fname, "r" ) ;
        char line [ 128 ]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
            int count=0;

        while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, fp ) != NULL ) /* read a line */ 
        {
            count++;
            if(head==NULL)
            {
                head=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
                fscanf(fp,"%s",string1);
                strcpy(head->mail,string1);
                head->counter=count;
                head->next=NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                node *tmp = (node *)malloc(sizeof (node));
                fscanf(fp,"%s",string1);
                strcpy(tmp->mail,string1);
                tmp->next = head;
                tmp->counter=count;
                head = tmp;
            }
        }

        fclose(fp); fp = fopen ( fname, "r" ) ;
        fclose(fp);
        //printf("%d",count_length);
        getch();
    }
```

The program gives an assertion error when it is run. Could anyone please help me debug it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [linked list usage to obtain data from file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842166/linked-list-usage-to-obtain-data-from-file)

Comment: How is this different from your last question?

Comment: it is..i thought the previous questions context was different hence created a new question

Comment: Please at least tell us, on which line the program crashes, and what the full error message is.

Comment: @cody...i edited the previous question to this...it was originally a different one...

Comment: while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, fp ) != NULL ) /* read a line */    it breaks at this line...

Comment: What exactly is the error message?

Comment: Debug assertion Failed[SPACE]  program: \\\[program path]\\\[name of prog].exe [SPACE] file : [path]\\fgets.c [SPACE] expression: (str !=null)

Comment: Add error checking: if( ( fp = fopen ( fname, "r" )) == NULL ) { perror( fname ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }

Answer (score 0):

This line is reading from the file into a buffer called line

```
gets ( line, sizeof line, fp ) != NULL
```

The inner bit of the loop should presumably do something with this line?  Instead of using fscanf to read from the file pointer, what about using "sscanf" to read from the string you've just read in?

Without more context it's difficult to know what you're trying to do.  If you are skipping blank lines, then I guess the code could make sense.

Comment: The assertion error was coming as i dint provide it with the text file........sorry guys...

Answer (score 0):

`node* head` is never initialized. Therefore `if (head==NULL)` will always evaluate to false (this is undefined behavior since it's not initialized)

On top of what Jeff Foster said, you are calling `fgets` along with `fscanf` which is reading a line of the file and then reading another string value. Therefore if `fgets` reads the last line of the file your call to `fscanf` will fail. This might have something to do with your assertion failure.